# FullCalendar New Appointment Button for Creating an Event

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I want to add button in the header that will open my window to create a new event. I got that working to the point of, how do I gain access to the view calendar API to create the event? Seems like I can only get that if I click somewhere in the calendar

```
 const customButtons = {
    newAppointment: {
      text: 'New Appointment',
      click: (event) => {
        console.log(event);
        toggleNewAppointment();
      }
    }
  }

  const headerToolbar = {
    start: 'title',
    center: 'newAppointment',
    end: 'today prev,next',
  }
```

Comment: To add a new event you must run the addEvent method - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent. Does that help? I wasn't quite clear exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to add your button to header so you can use it to create a new event. To achieve that check for the [eventObject](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/event-object) info and/or the [addEvent](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent) method or use your custom function in case you store your events in a database for example.

```js
calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  customButtons: {
    newAppointment: {
      text: 'New Appointment',
      click: () => {
        // Here you have to create an event object, since this function has no parameter from FullCalendar API
        const event = {
          id: 'a',
          title: 'my event',
          start: '2018-09-01'
        }
        console.log(event);
        createEventFuntion(event); // Send to your event save function
        // Or use the addEvent method instead
        // calendar.addEvent(event);
      }
    }
  },
  headerToolbar: {
    start: 'title',
    center: 'newAppointment',
    end: 'today prev,next',
  }
});
```

### Edit:

#### React

If you see [this example](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/blob/master/react/src/DemoApp.jsx), the way you can handle your events is almost the same as you do in Javascript. Also [check this info](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react#calendar-api) from documentation about how to access to the API.

```js
import React from 'react'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'

export default class DemoApp extends React.Component {

  // Create a reference
  calendarRef = React.createRef()

  state = {
    weekendsVisible: true,
    currentEvents: []
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='demo-app'>
        {this.renderSidebar()}
        <div className='demo-app-main'>
          <FullCalendar
            ref={this.calendarRef} // Here is the reference
            plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
            headerToolbar={{
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'newAppointment',
              right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            }}
            customButtons={{
              newAppointment: {
                  text: 'custom!',
                  click: function() {
                    alert('clicked the custom button!');
                    someMethod();
                  },
              },
            }}
            editable={true}
            selectable={true}
            // ...
            /* you can update a remote database when these fire:
            eventAdd={function(){}}
            eventChange={function(){}}
            eventRemove={function(){}}
            */
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  someMethod() {
    // Then you can use the reference to access to the API
    let calendarApi = this.calendarRef.current.getApi()
    calendarApi.addEvent()
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I missed the `addEvent` function. Thanks

Comment: So this makes sense, the problem is, in React, I do not have access to the CalendarAPi like the docs show. Any idea how to get this in react?

Comment: @jrock2004 check my edit, I'm not very familiar with react but it could by helpful to you

Comment: Yeah, I finally found that and was about to update. Created the ref is the way to go